# In sharepoint designer create custom form and set as default but on item edit and Item View forms are not open

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-designer

I am doing **migration from sharepoint 2013 to office 365.**
For one **list in sharepoint 2010 have infopath forms set as default.**
But because of some issue we need to create custom form using java script.
so i created Custom forms for New Item,Edit and View Item.

**Issue is:
These custom forms are set as default from designer but on select item for edit Item from list then previous infopath forms are open.**

**I want to open these newly created custom form open on item edit and Item View by default.**

Answer (score 0):

In 2013, go to `List > List Settings > Form Settings`, then select the `"Use default SharePoint form"` and click `OK`. I just went through this process replacing InfoPath with StratusForms.

The next time you visit the Form Settings, the only available selection is `"Customize the current form using Microsoft InfoPath."` Be sure to click cancel unless you want to go back to using InfoPath.